# What are the legal and tax implications of crypto lending?

Tags: united-states, taxes, loans, cryptocurrency

With high interest rates for crypto loans, I'm currently thinking of lending out my cryptocurrency on a crypto lending platform like Celsius Network. However, I'm not too sure about the implications of lending out crypto. First, is the interest treated differently than normal interest I would earn from a savings account? Would I need to register with FinCEN? Also, would lending out crypto on a lending platform make me an MSB?

I ask about MSB because when I signed up for a crypto wallet, my bank sent me a form asking if I was running an MSB (Money Services Business). They literally shut down my bank account until I filled out the form stating that I had opened the crypto wallet to trade crypto for personal investment purposes.

Anyways, I want to know if there is anything more to crypto lending other than putting in my tokens and collecting taxable interest.

Asking about US legal and tax implications.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add country of residence. I'm asking about the US.

Comment: One thing for sure is that you're going to have to update that form at the bank...

Comment: Why would I have to update the form? Would lending out crypto through a lending platform that offers financial services make me an MSB? What's the difference in doing that compared to simply earning money in a savings account?

Comment: Would you directly loan the coins, or let someone else be the middleman (EDIT: like Lendingtree)?

Comment: It would be like lending tree, expect it would be for crypto. Celsius Network, or the platform I'm planning on lending through, is actually a financial services company. So I would put in my crypto and would receive interest in the form or crypto from the company on a weekly basis.

Comment: @arj Whether you agree with it or not, if you have indicated 'x' to the bank, and they realize the actual situation is 'y', they may attempt to shut you down. If you are legally in the right (ie: perhaps they don't have the right to do this), perhaps you could then hire a lawyer and fight them to have your account remain open. If they are legally in the right, perhaps they also have the ability to apply penalties for you having misinformed them?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon That form was just to make sure I'm not operating as an MSB. It wasn't really about how I'm investing my crypto, whether I'm staking it or accruing interest on it. The only reason they shut down my bank account was that they're legally bound to know what their customers are doing. Since they were missing that info, they froze my account.

Answer (score 3):

You ask in one of your comments "*What's the difference in* [lending crypto through another 3rd party service] *compared to simply earning money in a savings account*?" You ask this question as a rhetorical rebuttal to the notion that you might need to inform your bank that the reason you opened your account is different than you initially indicated.

**Even just asking this question underlines the real problem with all of this - you don't appear to understand the risk in doing what you are considering**. From your perspective, having actual cash in a savings account is a relationship between you and your bank - and your bank is likely to be QUITE a better credit risk than someone borrowing crypto through a 3rd party service. Further, in the unlikely event that your bank ultimately collapses, your savings account is likely insured by your government [whether that is the case / to what limit, will depend on where you live].

If you lend 1 BTC to someone, what are the chances that they can pay you back? I would be incredibly nervous that someone borrowing crypto [instead of regular borrowing] is at a large risk of either gambling funds away, or even just disappearing into the night. Even if they pay you back, what if BTC has a price drop before you get it back? Lending it out removes your liquidity, which is a major risk in an already foolishly-risky asset. Personal lending in itself is quite risky, and adding in to this the risk of Crypto makes this a dubious prospect, at best.

Comment: To help visualize, if I borrow $10.000 to buy a car I may reasonably hope to pay back $10.500 next year, and you may check that I have assets to cover it. But if I borrow $10.000 in BTC, maybe next year I need to pay $30.000 to return that amount of BTC and I cannot afford it, and all you can get back is $15.000. Which means that you have lost $15.000 compared to what you would have if you had not borrowed the BTC. Also, if the value of the BTC decreases, you cannot sell it six months from now (say at $7.500) but will have to wait a year to recover a BTC that would then have a value of $5.000.

Comment: There are third party intermediaries who facilitate this lending, and protect you from another individual "doing a runner".  Sure, these companies are not as secure as major banks, but it is not like if that one person does not pay you are out of pocket.  The not being able to sell is a very real issue.

Comment: @Dave Are you suggesting to invest in 'trustless' bitcoin, only to turn around and put your trust in an organization maybe 1% the size of a bank domiciled in your own jurisdiction? Do you see the contradiction in aims?

Comment: Yes.  I am saying your answer makes it sound like you have to trust a single individual "If you lend 1 BTC to someone, what are the chances that they can pay you back?".  That is not the case.  An organization maybe 1% the size of a bank is more trustworthy than a single stranger, but less trustworthy than a bank.  I think you question is generally correct, just that it seems to understate that the Celsius Network provides some level of security.

Comment: @dave So 'Celsius Network' [whoever they are] guarantees your investment made to a 3rd party through their site? Why would they do that? Why would they take on the credit risk when acting only as facilitator? All of this screams poorly informed / bad idea to me.

Comment: [Kind of](https://celsius.network/earn-rewards-on-your-crypto), in much the same way a bank does.  It totally could be a scam or ponzi scheme as far as I know, but it is not lending to an individual.

Comment: @dave how many alarm bells are too many for you? At what point is it okay to admit that the protections offered by our modern financial institutions are preferential to the under-regulated Wild West of crypto?

Comment: I am really not arguing that this is a good instrument.  I am trying to use comments to improve the answer, by pointing out that it reads like you expect the OP to be trusting an individual, rather than an organisation that claims to have offices across 3 countries and $20 billion in "community assets".  There is a real risk that they are total scammers, but that is different from someone not being able to pay you back.  I would not give them any of my money.

Comment: I didn't write that comment in the way you're interpreting it. All I wanted to say is that if putting money in a savings account doesn't make me an MSB, then storing my crypto on a centralized lending platform shouldn't make me an MSB either.

Comment: Also, I'd like to add to this discussion and help shed some light on crypto lending. First and foremost, like @dave said, no one directly lends to another person. The crypto invested on a centralized financial service platform is accumulated in a pool fund. A person wanting a loan would apply to the financial service provider, and after KYC and other contractual agreements are made, the loan is given on a collateral for their crypto. Usually, the collateral is required to be double in value than that of the crypto loan.

Comment: If the person fails to pay the loan plus interest back, the collateral will be liquidated to make up for it. Now, of course some platforms will seem untrustworthy. Many are. But when a platform has close to a million registered users, more than $20B in community assets, more than $400M in paid out interest, and registered with FinCEN, it passes off as trustworthy to me. Of course, that's just my opinion though.

Comment: @arj Why would someone put 2x collateral up against a crypto loan? If you had 2 BTC on hand, why would you choose to borrow another BTC, instead of just using what you already own? Doing some digging shows they offer 17% interest. Do you understand how insanely risky that implies this is? That would imply that they are turning around and earning a profit on 'deposits' by offering loans at like 30%+ interest. Who would be borrowing from them at these rates, if not speculators looking for crypto price jumps?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Well borrowers might find this appealing for a couple of reasons, even though I find it very risky and unreasonable. First, they can take out stablecoins as a loan, which are pegged to the dollar, use them to buy crypto, and profit off of any volatile price spikes like with DOGE. Or they can speculate on borrowed crypto funds.

Comment: @arj borrowing money in order to speculate is a recipe for disaster. Aiming to profit off of such misery by lending funds to such speculators is definitely in the same cookbook.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Well, crypto is only loaned out to institutions. Individuals can only take out cash loans, which are actually provided at very reasonable rates (1%-7% APR) depending on how much collateral you put down that is. Most revenue comes from lending to exchanges/institutions for liquidity and investing purposes. So its not trying to profit off of individual speculators. High interest-paying crypto loans for exchanges and alike make sense since they can have multiple use cases (liquidity, shorting crypto, etc).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon They also run validator nodes for staking coins, in other words mining new tokens. So they also make money from that (which is why they can offer high interest rates for a few tokens). For example MATIC tokens, which I plan on staking, have 10% returns primarily because of high staking rewards.

Comment: @arj Sounds like your mind is made up, but remember that above all else, high rewards implies high risk. You are casually dropping the idea that it is perfectly normal for 'institutions' to borrow funds for shorting crypto, but rest assured that this is the sort of activity that would have most seasoned investors' eyes bugging out of their heads. You shouldn't lend money to someone walking into a casino.

Answer (score 3):

> With high interest rates for crypto loans, I'm currently thinking of lending out my cryptocurrency on a crypto lending platform like Celsius Network. However, I'm not too sure about the implications

The main implication is the high interest rates mean that the risk is **high**.

> Anyways, I want to know if there is anything more to crypto lending other than putting in my tokens and collecting taxable interest.

Has Celsius Network explained you how do they plan on paying you, say, 1.10 BTC next year for each BTC you give them now? Where will that 0.10 BTC come from (*)? Unlike rabbits, it is not that you put some of them together and then magically more of them appear. They must do *something*.

Maybe they plan to lend to business who can invest it and to produce extra value to pay for it. But then they are working as a bank, why should they give extra interest? Also, it is very risky for everyone, maybe the business they lend to can repay back the money with %20 more, but, will it be enough to buy your BTC back then?

Maybe they plan to sell your BTC while the price is high and buy back to return yours when the price is low. But they are taking a risk that maybe you are not comfortable with, if they are wrong and the price does not get lower it will be you the one who loses the BTC ("sorry, we explained to you at clause 412.f at page 212 of the contract"). Or maybe it is not in the contract and they promise you "100% guarantee" that you will get your BTC back, and just declare bankruptcy.

Maybe it is just a Ponzi scheme. They will tell everybody that they have so much money, hoping that people won't want it back because everything goes so well.

And of course, apart of the above there is the issue that if the price of your crypto goes down you will not be able to sell it earyly.

(*) Apart from the extra BTC needed to pay for their operation expenses and profits.